# How to get the current element count of an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Say I have this array

```
$array = array('pen' => 'blue', 'paper' => 'red', 'ink' => 'white');
```

When I loop through it

```
$string = '';
foreach ($array AS $key=>$value) {
    $string .= $key . ' = ' . $value;
}
```

I want to get the "line number" of the element the loop is currently on.

If the loop is on "pen" I would get 1.
If the loop is on "paper" I would get 2.
If the loop is on "ink" I would get 3.

Is there an array command for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You will have to increment an index counter manually:

```
$string = '';
$index = 0;
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    $string .= ++$index . ") ". $key . ' = ' . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to extract values from array. It indexes array numerically and $key will be the index of value in loop.

```
$array = array('pen' => 'blue', 'paper' => 'red', 'ink' => 'white');
$array = array_values($array);

$string = '';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $string .= $key + 1 . ' = ' . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) { // For each element of the array
    print("Current non-associative index: ".$i."<br />\n"); // Output the current index

    $i++; // Increment $i by 1
}
```

Hope that helps.